# compare temporary columns in sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that includes small_bags, large_bags, xlarge_bags and total_bags.

I run this query to create a temporary column total_calc which is the same as total_bags.

```
SELECT 
  region,
  total_bags,
  Small_Bags+Large_Bags+XLarge_Bags as total_calc
FROM `coursera-data-analyst-356606.avocado_data.avocado_prices`
```

I just want to compare whether there are any mistakes in total_bags. what query should I run next to find out which rows differ in total_bags and total_calc columns? After some research, as I understood, I have to run  `where Total_Bags <> total_calc` but it does not work if I put the where clause in this query. I tried to run this query but it won't work. I believe, I have to create a subquery and include a where clause there but I don't know how to do it. Could someone help me with this?

```
SELECT 
  region,
  total_bags,
  Small_Bags+Large_Bags+XLarge_Bags as total_calc
FROM `coursera-data-analyst-356606.avocado_data.avocado_prices` 
where Total_Bags <> total_calc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, [ALIAS](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) cannot be used directly in where clause within the same block. Instead try:

```
SELECT 
  region,
  total_bags,
  Small_Bags+Large_Bags+XLarge_Bags as total_calc
FROM `coursera-data-analyst-356606.avocado_data.avocado_prices` 
where ROUND(Total_Bags,2) <> ROUND((Small_Bags+Large_Bags+XLarge_Bags),2)
```

Or you can use a temporary table:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
  region,
  ROUND(total_bags,2) as totalBags,
  ROUND(Small_Bags+Large_Bags+XLarge_Bags,2) as total_calc
FROM `coursera-data-analyst-356606.avocado_data.avocado_prices` ) a
where totalBags <> total_calc
```

Comment: Thank you fro your reply. I did as you said. but it shows identical values not different.
check the screenshot please.
https://imgur.com/N41ZDqk

Comment: Not a problem, see my updated answer. I didn't know the SUM of `Bags` could be in decimal places

Comment: thank you for your quick response. we are almost there:)) could you please look at the new screenshot? https://imgur.com/cYqBTVH
I believe, we have to round numbers even more, right? Can we say that numbers are still identical?

Comment: I believe this is the result you are expecting. totalBags is not equal to total_calc